# How to get coordinate from MS-Word?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

For example, I have a document named **first.doc** containing two words which are **Hello World**. I want to get the coordinates of **Hello World**. Is there any method to get these coordinates?

Comment: What do you mean by the coordinates of a word?

Comment: @Jakob distance from top and left of the page.

Comment: @Jakob The position in page

Answer (score 2):

[`Range.Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.find.aspx) and [`Window.GetPoint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.window.getpoint.aspx) can be used to solve this problem:

```
Application application = new Application();
Document wordDoc = application.Documents.Open(@"C:\first.doc");

Range range = application.ActiveDocument.Content;
range.Find.Execute("hello world");
int left, top, width, height;
application.ActiveWindow.GetPoint(out left, out top, out width, out height, range);
```